I would like display date exactly how it is on database using day.js
I have an app that I built where users can create trips. These trips have starts and end dates. Now, a user created a trip and sets the dates to be:
start date: 3rd of January, 2025
end date: 10 of January, 2025.
Problem started when users who wishes to book the trip were seeing different displayed dates. I knew I have messed things up and would like to know how best to approach this.
They want the dates to be same irrespective of the place the user wishes to book. This means that the user making the booking should see the exact date the trip creator had set for start and end dates.
They only wants displayed date and not time.
Here is how I am handling date for now. The app was built with next.js and express.js for backend. In the frontend, I am using React Callender for dates UI. I am using Day.js for date display and creation.
When the user creates the date in the frontend, I am storing it this way in backend.
import utc from "dayjs/plugin/utc";
var dayjs = require("dayjs");
dayjs.extend(utc);

export const convertDate = (date: Date | string) => {

  const converted = dayjs(new Date(date)).utc().format(); //dayjs.utc(newDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

  return converted;
};


This output for instance using the trip that was created: "2025-01-03T05:00:00Z" for start date and
2025-01-10T05:00:00Z.
On the client side, I am displaying the date this way:
 dayjs(response?.startDate).format("MMM-DD-YYYY")
 dayjs(response?.endDate).format("MMM-DD-YYYY")

Now, one of the users who wanted to book this trip saw trip dates as follows:
Start date: 2nd of January, 2025
End date: 9th of January, 2025. Obviously it is timezone issue.
We would like the user to see exactly 3rd of January, 2025 to 10th of January, 2025 irrespective of the user's timezone.
How can I achieve this?

The issue is occurring because you're converting to UTC on the backend but not specifying how to handle the timezone when displaying dates on the frontend.

On backend:
// trips.controller.ts
import { createTripDates } from './date-utils';

app.post('/trips', (req, res) => {
  const { startDate, endDate } = req.body;
  
  // Convert dates to UTC and strip time information
  const tripDates = createTripDates(startDate, endDate);
  
  // Store in database (will save as YYYY-MM-DD)
  await Trip.create({
    ...req.body,
    startDate: tripDates.startDate,
    endDate: tripDates.endDate,
  });
});

on Frontend
// TripDetails.tsx
import { formatTripDates } from './date-utils';

const TripDetails = ({ trip }) => {
  const { startDate, endDate } = formatTripDates(trip);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Trip dates: {startDate} to {endDate}</p>
    </div>
  );
};


This means that in front end, I will not use Day.js to display the date anymore? If I store date with the format in database, there are places where I used date to handle logic such as knowing when trip expires. I relied on day.js to compare for me. Will storing dates in format only that strips it off time information still work?

The thing is I still need Day.js for formatting in client side.

When storing dates in your database, always convert them to UTC ISO format by modifying your existing convertDate function. The key change is to use startOf('day') to ensure all dates are set to midnight UTC, which prevents timezone shifts. In the frontend, you'll continue using Day.js, but you'll need to add the UTC plugin and always use UTC for formatting display dates. So when you fetch a trip from the backend and want to display its dates, use dayjs.utc(response.startDate).format("MMM DD, YYYY") instead of just dayjs(response.startDate).format().

The .utc() part tells Day.js to interpret and format the date in UTC, which ensures everyone sees the same date regardless of their timezone.

You didn't mention how I needed to modify the conertDate function to ensure that the UTC dates are in midnight.
